# Como funciona a propriedade display?

Tags: css, css3

Eu estive pesquisando melhor a funcionalidade (valores) `display` e suas funcionalidades. Percebi que ela possui muitas possibilidades. Algumas bem óbvias e outras um tanto complexa para o desenvolvedor iniciante.

Acredito que essas funcionalidades abaixo são as mais confusas para o desenvolvedor iniciante:

- `flex`
- `inline-flex`
- `list-item`
- `run-in` (essa é uma que eu nunca vi ser utilizada)
- `table-cell`

**Como elas são usada?**

**Alguma dessas funcionalidades são essências para o design responsivo?**

**Algum bom exemplo de utilização?**

Comment: Pergunta interessante, jovem .+1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters muito obrigado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Olá!
Posso de repente esclarecer algumas dessas dúvidas.
Eu diria que nenhuma dessas são "essenciais" para o design responsivo, porém a `flex` é uma muito utilizada para tal, hoje em dia, já que ela foi feita para facilitar o design fluido.

• O `flex`: Facilita a responsividade e fluidez com novos atributos que simplificam coisas que geralmente são bem mais complexas de atingir com um block. **Exemplo:** É muito simples alinhar verticalmente elementos em flex.

• O `inline-flex`: Vejo ser utilizado bem menos, mas creio eu que deve dar funções de flex para elementos `inline` que são geralmente como texto. Estou para ver ser mais utilizado.

• O `list-item`: É o default de elementos em lista `ul`, `li`. O objeto será formatado como lista.

• O `run-in`: Essa é simplesmente para alinhar um header ao texto. Como nesse exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

• O `table-cell`: É o default de células de tabela.

Answer (score 5):

A propriedade `display` é a propriedade mais importante do `CSS` para controlar o layout, o valor padrão pode varias de elemento para elemento, de modo geral o valor padrão é `display:block` ou `display:inline`.
Abaixo listarei somente as funcionalidade classificas como **funcionalidades mais confusas** de acordo com a pergunta, p/ acessar uma lista com todas as funcionalidades e seus exemplos de uso segue o link: [w3schools css display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

- `flex`

A propriedade flex específica o comprimento do item, em relação ao restante dos itens flexíveis dentro do mesmo container, de certa forma ela adapta o item em questão em relação aos outros itens flexíveis.

- `inline-flex`

A diferença entre `inline-flex` e `flex` é que o inline-flex não faz os itens flex serem exibidos em uma única linha, ele mostra o container flexível em linha como um todo.

- `list-item`

Um elemento renderizado com a propriedade `list-item` terá o mesmo comportamento de um elemento `block`, além disso essa propriedade vai gerar um marcador(marker box), seu estilo pode ser alterado através da propriedade `list-style`

- `run-in`

A propriedade `run-in`  funciona do seguinte modo: Se a caixa run-in contém uma caixa `block`, funciona como um bloco;
Se uma caixa `block` segue a caixa `run-in`, a caixa run-in torna-se a primeira caixa `inline` da caixa bloco.
Este propriedade é utilizada por exemplo, para juntar um cabeçalho a um texto abaixo dele sem prejudicar a semântica em questão e para prevenir futuros erros que poderiam aparecem forçando a posição com outras técnicas de layout. P/ mais informações sobre a propriedade `run-in`:[CSS tricks run-in](https://css-tricks.com/run-in/)

- `table-cell`

Faz com que o elemento se comporte como uma `<td>`