# Existe apenas display inline e block por padrão nos elementos ou outros?

Tags: html, css

Eu vejo bastante pela Internet falarem tanto de apenas `display: inline` e `display: block`, mas nas tabelas, por exemplo, no elemento `<table>` a exibição dele é `display: table`, eu gostaria de saber se:

- Existem outras exibições padrões nos elementos além dos mencionados?
- Porque apenas `inline` e `block` são relevantes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como funciona a propriedade display?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190005/como-funciona-a-propriedade-display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, basicamente os elementos padrão do HTML5 vem por default com os tipos:

- block (h1, h2, h3..., p, div, header, section, article, etc...)
- inline (span, strong, em, image, etc)
- inline-block (input, select...)
- list-item (li, ...)
- table, table-row, table-cell, etc... (aplicados por default nos elementos de tabela)
- none (head, title, meta)

Na lista acima podem existir mais alguns talvez que eu esteja esquecendo... mas acho que não.

A questão não é ser relevante... mas sim, são os que existem desde os primórdios do css e por isso são os essenciais..

Os valores mais recentes da propriedade display (flex, grid e os outros) não vem por padrão do browser em nenhum elemento html nativo. Mas você os pode usar para satisfazer sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado, amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitos mais, cada um suprindo uma necessidade diferente. Por exemplo:
Content, grid, flex, flex-inline, entre outros.

São considerados mais relevantes por terem mais tempo de uso (mais antigos se preferir). Hoje em dia eu procuro fazer quase tudo com flex, pela adaptação a Grids.

Você pode acompanhar todos nesse site: [w3schools/css-display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Por exemplo, o elemento `<p>` ele tem a exibição padrão para `block`, mas esses que você citou quais utilizam por padrão essas exibições?